How to configure an Entra App Registration to include appname in redirect URI
I have an ASP.NET MVC web app deployed at https://apps.domain/canvasadminstage where canvasdminstage is a webapp running in IIS under the root domain.

The app is using MSAL and the app registration in EntraID is returning a valid token. However, it is not redirecting to the full redirect URI defined in the app registration. It is removing the appname from the response.
So the configured redirect URI is as below.

When I authenticate and go through MFA I get redirected to

I can re-insert the appname in the URL manually and the app loads correctly.
The app startup is configured to load the correct redirect URI depending on environment (this is obviously different from the localhost entry for debugging.)

I have tried many forms of reply URI but get the same result irrespective of what I do.

if possible can you share your code?

are you using custom domain ?

The redirect URi is invalid.Please refer this MDcoc

Thanks to everyone who has replied. @Sirra, the code is just too massive to be able to post/obsfucate. I thought custom domains were associated with using application proxy and this is not the case here. But I could be wrong.

@Harshitha, the reply URI seems to be valid according to that document (and the inline examples when configuring the app registration in Azure). Thanks for all comments and suggestions though.
